# Prove that $Fr(Fr(Fr(A))) = Fr(Fr(A))$

Tags: general-topology

I want to learn topology and I found this excercise in my book:
Prove that $Fr(Fr(Fr(A))) = Fr(Fr(A))$ (in any topological space).
By definition $Fr(Fr(Fr(A))) = Cl(Fr(Fr(A))) \setminus Int(Fr(Fr(A)))$.
What is more $Cl(Fr(Fr(A)) = Fr(Fr(A))$.
So I need to prove that $Int(Fr(Fr(A))) = \emptyset $, but here I'm stuck.
Please help me? :)

Comment: What's $Fr(A)$?

Comment: It is defined as $Cl(A) \setminus Int(A)$

Comment: Ah, ok. $Fr$ like *frontier*. More commonly named *boundary*, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The boundary of any closed set is nowhere dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1143332/4280). $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ is a closed set. So that interior is empty.

Comment: Ok, I think now I see it :D

Comment: Ok, I think I can see it. Thank you! (I haven't heard of nowhere dense set before).

Comment: @Kamil it's a pretty natural notion.